# Update input fields based on calculation ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have two input fields and allowing user to type on either inputs to perform meters to kilometers conversion. I'm trying to use useEffect to watch for changes and update either input field but it's not functioning correctly.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    let res = parseInt(event.target.value) * 1000;
    setValue2(res.toString());
  }, [value])
  useEffect(() => {
    let res = parseInt(event.target.value) / 1000;
    setValue(res.toString());
  }, [value2])
  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
  const onChange2 = (event) => {
    setValue2(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>Meters</div>
      <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <div>Kilometers</div>
      <input value={value2} onChange={onChange2} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Don't use effects. Do the calculations in the `onChange` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `useEffect` to achieve what you want :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [meters, setMeters] = useState(null);
  const [kilometers, setKilometers] = useState(null);

  const handleMeterInput = (event) => {
    setMeters(event.target.value);
    setKilometers(event.target.value / 1000);
  };

  const handleKiloInput = (event) => {
    setKilometers(event.target.value);
    setMeters(event.target.value * 1000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2> Meters to Kilometers converter </h2>
      <div>
        <strong>Meters :</strong>
        <input type="number" value={meters} onChange={handleMeterInput} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Kilometers :</strong>
        <input type="number" value={kilometers} onChange={handleKiloInput} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-williams-z2ioso?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for your help, so many ways to do same thing in react.